# How to use ALT commands in a terminal on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal

In iTerm2 (and OS X in general), hitting <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> inserts †. How can I use the alt key to send the correct keystroke to iTerm2 ( in this case, in order to swap two words).

PS: Using <kbd>esc</kbd> instead is not the solution. Esc is not a modifier (keystrokes are not repeatable).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both iTerm and Terminal have preferences for using option as a meta key.

[image]
[image]

You can also use [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/KeyBindings/Emacs%20Opt%20Bindings.dict) to add support for keybindings like `M-f` and `M-u` to other text views.

Comment: In my case, with the setting you are suggesting (Left option key acts as Meta), alt-t results in a question mark after a slight delay, but +ESC does the job.